# How to get JMS to front end

Tags: java, message-queue, messaging

I currently have a web application and I would like to add a messaging feature to it.
In order to do that, I use JMS(actually OpenMQ, the implementation provided with Glassfish 3).
The problem is that I do not know how to get the message notification from the background(from the listener) to the foreground.
I am using JSF as a framework, if it does have an importance.
Could you please tell me how should I notify the user about a received message(like a chat).
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), a programming model that allows the server to **push** data to a client. There are implementations for JSF, look at [this blog post about Richfaces integration](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/GettingStartedWithRichFaces40Push) for an example.

HTML 5 specifies [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) that can be used for server push, but not all browsers support it.

The simple alternative is to simply poll the server at regular intervals, that might create a lot of unnecessary messages though.